# How can I print elapsed time in ms using python

Tags: python, datetime

I am able to compute elapsed time, but I dont know how to print results in ms (i need integer, like this: 20ms, 30ms..)

```
import datetime

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print 'some long procedure'
elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
print int(elapsed).strftime("%s")) * 1000 #<------- not working
```

Answer (score 5):

The `total_seconds` method of `datetime.timedelta` objects returns the number of seconds, as a float, so it includes the fractions of second - see [timedelta.total_seconds](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds).

So, you just have to multiply it by 1000 to convert it to milliseconds, and keep the integer part.

```
import datetime

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print 'some long procedure'
elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time

print(int(elapsed.total_seconds()*1000))
```